# inserting a javascript to change div opacity based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, insert, scroll

First, I know this has been covered multiple times, but
I just can't figure out how to insert the script properly...

I want a div to change opacity when scroll is getting down...

what I'm having now: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WKZKp/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#liners').each(function(index) {
        if (($(this).offset().top-st) < 50) {
            $(this).css({
                'opacity': (0 + (st / $(this).offset().top))
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({'opacity': 0.1});
        }
    })
});
```

It doesn't work AT ALL, not even near to.. I would need help 
I don't know if i'm writing it correctly too!

Thanks for answers and if you need more infos from me just ask!

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please test your fiddle (you've put JS+CSS in the wrong boxes and you didn't include jQuery).

[Here is your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/WKZKp/3/).

I've change CSS definition to make it easier to test (I used smaller height than you). Other than that, here is the relevant JS code:

```
$('div#liners').scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var h = this.scrollHeight;
    $(this).css({
        'opacity': 1 - st / h
    });
});
```

You need to capture `div`'s scroll, get the size of the content (`h` in my code) and to scroll position.

**Edit:** It just occurred to me you want it all to depend on the window scroll, not div content (I don't see a purpose for that, so I didn't think of it before). In that case, just adapt my code to capture window's scroll, as you did in your original attempt.